# Share database between apps without duplicating models in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two apps that I want to use the same database. One app is simply to migrate data into the main app's DB.

It would be great to be able to use Sequelize in both apps, and simply connect the migration app to the main app's DB.

However, my understanding of Sequelize is I won't be able to access `db.models.MyModel` unless the models in JS are actually imported into that app's instance of Sequelize. But I don't want to duplicate code between apps and have to manage changes on both.

Is there a way to do this with Sequelize? Or should I look at something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you won't be able to access models unless they are imported into the particular instance (unless you use raw queries).

You could store you model definitions in a separate repository / folder, and require them from there in both your apps.